# How does Mathematica calculate $\sin(\pi/5)$?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, implementation-details, trigonometry

Consider:

```
Sin[Pi/5]
```

which returns: $$\sqrt{\frac58-\frac{\sqrt5}{8}}$$

Does anyone know how to figure out the trigonometric identities used by *Mathematica* to produce this answer?

I gave this a try:

```
WolframAlpha["sin(pi/5)"]
```

but it did not provide any steps.

Comment: How *Mathematica* itself calculates it is only known to its developers.  How one might calculate it with pen and paper belongs on Math.SE, I think.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi5.html)

Comment: According to [Goldstine](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/87252.88059), Ptolemy started with `Sin[Pi/5]` and `Sin[Pi/3]` when constructing his "table of chords," probably from [Eu. XIII.10](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXIII/propXIII10.html).

Comment: See also [http://functions.wolfram.com/](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/27/ShowAll.html)

Comment: @Szabolcs I don't think you need to be a developer to guess that it works by a simple lookup.

Answer (score 17):

In the course of answering this question, I ran into a little bit of weirdness that doesn't square with my experience with previous versions of *Mathematica*. I think writing this answer is as good a time as any to bring it up.

Firstly, there is this tantalizing line from the [internal implementation notes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#1832):

> `FunctionExpand` uses an extension of Gauss's algorithm to expand trigonometric functions with arguments that are rational multiples of $\pi$.

Indeed, in the old versions of *Mathematica*, `FunctionExpand[]` certainly was able to convert trigonometric values at rational multiples of $\pi$ to the corresponding radical values (possibly involving complex numbers). This hinged on the function `` Developer`TrigToRadicals[] ``, and in fact one could use this directly instead of `FunctionExpand[]`.

Now, however, `FunctionExpand[]` no longer seems to perform this conversion. Using `` Developer`TrigToRadicals[] `` throws an error message saying that it is obsolete, and that one should now use `ToRadicals[]` instead. The kicker is that `ToRadicals[]` and `` Developer`TrigToRadicals[] `` return different-looking (but numerically equivalent) results, which means the internal algorithms have been changed somewhat.

Quite a mystery.

---

Now, "Gauss's algorithm" is not terribly informative, considering that Gauss was a rather prodigious producer of mathematical results. However, there is a section in Gauss's [*Disquisitiones Arithmeticae*](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN235993352|LOG_0011&physid=PHYS_0416) (sorry, I couldn't find a free English translation) that relates to a number-theoretic view of the roots of unity (and thus, trigonometric functions). In particular, he outlines in [one section](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=PPN235993352|LOG_0012&physid=PHYS_0455) a recursive method for determining explicit radical expressions of roots of unity.

There is, however, a more modern method that improves on the asymptotic complexity of Gauss's algorithm. In [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/240065.240070), A. Weber presents an improvement of Gauss's original algorithm that hinges on an efficient way to evaluate the "recursive step" in the original method. A Maple implementation of this improved method is presented in the paper; I will wager that this method, with possibly a few proprietary extensions, is the guts behind `` Developer`TrigToRadicals[] ``. (It should be noted that Weber's paper also points to alternative algorithms for explicitly producing radical expressions; I have not been able to find those references, so I cannot say much about them. Maybe an expert can chime in.)

As for the original question, although $\sin(\pi/5)$ is automatically converted to a radical result in the current version of *Mathematica*, it is likely that the improved Gauss algorithm was used to produce the radical expression in the first place.

Comment: `ToRadicals[Cos[Pi/257]]` fails to give the correct answer. ``Developer`TrigToRadicals`` is slower, but is correct.

Comment: The current code (V12) may be inspected with ``Simplify`TrigToRealRadicals;
System`TrigToRadicalsDump`sin // DownValues`` or `PrintDefinitions`.