# Can Mathematica give the solutions to x^n - 1 = 0 in their radical form

Tags: equation-solving

If I input:

```
Solve[x^3 - 1 == 0]
```

Mathematica returns:

> {{x -> 1}, {x -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}

I want to see the roots expressed as radicals for example:

> 1/2 + Sqrt(-3)/2

Comment: Have you tried `ComplexExpand`? I'm not sure it does what you want for high order roots. `FunctionExpand` will expand them if they can be expressed in terms of square roots (see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107577)).

Comment: Try `ExpToTrig[]` and report back.

Comment: It appears that ExpToTrig and ComplexExpand will  return all the solutions of x^n -1 ==0 in radicals for n < 7.  Table[ExpToTrig[Solve[x^n - 1 == 0][[All, 1, 2]]], {n, 1, 10}]