# Why doesn't Mathematica know the exact value of some trivial trigonometric functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

The trigonometric functions for half angles have well-defined and simple rules. For example
$$\tan\left(\frac x2\right)=\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\frac1{\csc x+\cot x}$$
But I can't get the exact value for some expressions as simple as $\tan(\pi/8)$. No matter what I tried, Mathematica wouldn't understand that it's equal to $\sqrt2-1$, for example:

```
Simplify[Tan[Pi/8] + 1 - Sqrt[2]]
```

does nothing. I tried `TrigReduce`, `TrigExpand`, `TrigFactor`, `FullSimplify` and some other unrelated functions and they all failed to give the exact value of $\tan(\pi/8)$. This became ironic when I checked some other angles such as $\pi/12$ and turned out it *does* know e.g. $\sin(\pi/12)$ whose only way of calculation is apparently, through half angle formulas.

Why this happens and how can I get Mathematica to calculate such values when they do have an exact expression?

Comment: Of course, the question is a bit flawed because `Tan[Pi/8]` **is** an exact numerical constant.

Comment: @JohnDoty please feel free to edit it if you can think of better words. My vocabulary is not that great.

Comment: Well, what is it that you want, really? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: `Tan[Pi/8] // N // RootApproximant`

Comment: With version `12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)`, `FullSimplify[Tan[Pi/8] + 1 - Sqrt[2]]` yields `0`.

Comment: From a possible duplicate, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104223/how-does-mathematica-calculate-sin-pi-5/107577#107577, this quote from the documentation: "`FunctionExpand` uses an extension of Gauss's algorithm to expand trigonometric functions with arguments that are rational multiples of π."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An answer to [How does Mathematica calculate $\sin(\pi/5)$?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104223/how-does-mathematica-calculate-sin-pi-5/107577#107577) by @J.M. points out that in the [Notes on Internal Implementation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html), it is implied that `FunctionExpand` is the way to expand trigonometric functions in terms of radicals when possible:

> `FunctionExpand` uses an extension of Gauss's algorithm to expand trigonometric functions with arguments that are rational multiples of π.

```
FunctionExpand[Tan[Pi/8]]
(*  Sqrt[(2 - Sqrt[2])/(2 + Sqrt[2])]  *)
```

The internal function that does what the OP wants is called `` Simplify`TrigToRealRadicals[] ``, which is called by `FunctionExpand` and `ToRadicals` in this case.  It in turn calls a function like `` System`TrigToRadicalsDump`tan[] ``, which computes the conversion.  These function memoize their results, which makes timing them a challenge.  However, the timings below show that `FunctionExpand` does a lot of unnecessary work.  We give a complicated example.  At first, `FunctionExpand` does nothing, and `ToRadicals` returns the simplified expansion in terms of the complex exponential function.

```
FunctionExpand[Cos[π/257]]
(* Cos[π/257]  <-- takes <0.02s *)

ToRadicals[Cos[π/257]]
(*  -(1/2) (-1)^(256/257) (1 + (-1)^(2/257))  <-- takes 0.004s *)
```

If the trig-to-radicals functionality has been loaded, then we get a different behavior.  I cannot say for certain what functions cause the loading of the package.  The first time I tested, it had been loaded and I got results like those below.  The second, I retested with a fresh kernel and got the above, which confused me for a while.

```
Simplify`TrigToRealRadicals; (* load/initialize *)
System`TrigToRadicalsDump`cos[π/257]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {146.975, Null}  <-- the expansion is now memoized *)

ToRadicals[Cos[π/257]] // LeafCount
(*  263365  <-- in terms of (real) radicals; takes only 0.06s *)
```

Here's a speed comparison, assuming the initialization of `` System`TrigToRadicalsDump`cos[π/257] `` has been done.

```
Simplify`TrigToRealRadicals[Cos[π/257]]; // RepeatedTiming
ToRadicals[Cos[π/257]]; // RepeatedTiming
RootReduce[Cos[π/257]]; // RepeatedTiming
FunctionExpand[Cos[π/257]]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*
  { 0.0579771, Null}
  { 0.0593911, Null}
  { 1.28168,   Null}
  {37.3825,    Null}
*)
```

Comment: The formatting of third paragraph makes it hard to read/understand. By the way, is there anything special about number `257` or is it chosen randomly?

Comment: @polfosol n=257 is a prime such that [a regular n-gon can be constructed by ruler and compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon). That comes down to writing `Cos[Pi/257]` in terms of square roots, more or less. The example is borrowed from the linked question. Such primes have to be Fermat primes, which have the form `2^(2^k)+1`. (And thanks for alerting me to a missing backtick.)

Answer (score 10):

```
TrigToExp[Tan[Pi/8]] // FullSimplify
-1 + Sqrt[2]
```

Or, even better:

```
Tan[Pi/8] // RootReduce
-1 + Sqrt[2]
```

Comment: Who would have thought, of all the functions, `RootReduce` would do the job? a strange world we live in...

Comment: @polfosol You apparently wanted an explicit algebraic number, so `RootReduce` made perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 9):

Try to use `ToRadicals[Tan[Pi/8]]//FullSimplify`