# Replacing a trigonometric value

Tags: replacement, trigonometry

It looks like `MMA` cannot evaluate `Tan[42°]` but it can be written as

(-Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + Sqrt[6 (5 + Sqrt[5])])/(2 Sqrt[7 - Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[30 - 6 Sqrt[5]]])

I have another expression where `MMA` includes `Tan[42°]`. How can I replace the `Tan[42°]` in this expression with the expression above, besides C/P? TIA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Why doesn't Mathematica know the exact value of some trivial trigonometric functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257468/why-doesnt-mathematica-know-the-exact-value-of-some-trivial-trigonometric-funct/257520#257520)

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[Tan[42 \[Degree]]]]
```

> ```
> (*  Sqrt[7 + 2 Sqrt[5] - 2 Sqrt[15 + 6 Sqrt[5]]]  *)
> ```

OP's expression:

```
(-Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 
    Sqrt[6 (5 + Sqrt[5])])/(2 Sqrt[
     7 - Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[30 - 6 Sqrt[5]]]) // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> (*  Sqrt[7 + 2 Sqrt[5] - 2 Sqrt[15 + 6 Sqrt[5]]]  *)
> ```

Replacement:

```
expr /. t_Tan?NumericQ :> FullSimplify@FunctionExpand[t]
```

Or, possibly:

```
Exp[Tan[42 \[Degree]]] // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> (*  E^Sqrt[7 + 2 Sqrt[5] - 2 Sqrt[15 + 6 Sqrt[5]]]  *)
> ```

Comment: I don't understand the last. Why E^?

Comment: @mf67 You didn't give an example of "another expression where MMA includes `Tan[42°]`," so I made up `Exp[Tan[42 \[Degree]]]` to show that `FunctionExpand` works when the trig. value is inside an expression.

Comment: Aha! OK. All clear now.

Comment: An equivalent, if slightly longer, route: `Tan[42 ° // FunctionExpand] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 2):

```
expression /. 
 Tan[42 Degree] -> (-Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[5]] + 
     Sqrt[6 (5 + Sqrt[5])])/(2 Sqrt[
      7 - Sqrt[5] + Sqrt[30 - 6 Sqrt[5]]])
```